# Video Streaming from an object storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, video-streaming

As the title depicts I am trying to stream a video from an object storage i.e minIO.

Use case : I am working on social media application for a feature called "reels" aka short videos and storing the saved videos to minio.

Problem : While scrolling through the already posted videos I am finding a buffer lag between the videos as we are accessing the videos using the url generated by the minio server.

My approach : I have planned to introduce a streaming server which can stream videos from the object storage as mentioned above which can solve the buffering issue.

I have gone through the following open source servers,

- nginx rtmp
- apache flink

While going through the above I am unable to find proper documentation where it fetches a video from object storage and streams it to the application.

Help?

I would like to know the following,

- if the above approach is right and if its right how do I configure these servers to fetch from minio.
- if this isn't right would be helpful if you could assist me with another approach.